# kohana orm select users with all given roles

Tags: php, select, orm, kohana-3

I need to select users having all given roles.
In Model_User i have:

```
 public function getUsers() {

   $users = $this
            ->join('roles_users')->on('roles_users.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->where('role_id', '=', ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'login')))
            ->and_where('role_id', '=', ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'simple_user')));

    return $users;
}
```

But this is not working.
Regards.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552875/kohana-3-auth-module-getting-users-with-staff-or-manager-role

Comment: Thank You, but i know this question. I need to select users with both roles together ('and', not 'or'). Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you will follow link that Ryan posts you can modify that script this way:

```
public function get users() {

    $login = ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login'))->users->find_all()->as_array();
    $simple_user = ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'simple_user'))->users->find_all()->as_array();

    return array_intersect($login, $simple_user);
}
```

Then as a result you should have only user that have both roles.

Another small thing is that you should follow kohana convention in your function name.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach for this problem:

```
public function getUsers() {
    // Get IDs of all users having "login" role
    $active_users = ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'login'))->users->find_all()->as_array(null, 'id');
    // Select all users having roles "simple user" and "login"
    $users = ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'simple_user'))->users->where('id', 'IN', $active_users)->find_all();
    return $users;
}
```